# How to use Cloud Firestore with React Native and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a newbie in React Native and trying to learn using Cloud Firestore.

Basically, I haven't figure it out the whole road map to follow when you want to use Cloud Firestore combined with authentication in React Native and Firebase

I've successfully added Firebase authentication into my app.

The data is a list of places created by the users. I store that in Redux store, and generate a `FlatList` on the screen.

The question now is how can I store each list made by user to the cloud? 
Like when the user login again, he/she can see the data he/she created. 
Do we also need to persist the data ?

I'd love to learn some articles, or a general instructions for the whole progress (no code is needed), like step 1 or what requirements, what states of the app we need to list out, etc.. so I can get my hand down to figure it by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) of the Cloud Firestore is really useful.

Store something on the cloud Firestore is really easy. For example, if you write something like this:

```js
const doc = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('bucketName')
    .doc('docId')
    .get()
    .data()
```

you get the document with the id `docId` from the bucket `bucketName`. If the document and/or the bucket does not exist you simply got undefined.

---

Instead, if you write:

```js
const docId = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('bucketName')
    .add({
      name: "Marco",
      born: "1993"
    })
```

you get the id `docId` of a new document that has been added to the collection `bucketName` containing the object `{...}`.

---

No schema is needed. If you add a document to a bucket that does not exist, Firebase create the bucket and then add the document to it.

---

From React Native you need to trigger a function and call, for example, the code I provided above. With the returned value you can use redux, save the data into the store and use them around the application.

Comment: -Will it be optimized and proper if I do that in the Redux reducer ? Like send the data to Firestore at the same time with dispatching the actions (actions file including the data sending function)
- Also, should we persist the that data, or we'll request from the firestore everytime the user want to view the data ?

Comment: @Marwin You need to do that in a function and dispatch a reducer action only with the returned data, like this: `dispatch({ type: SET_DATA, data: doc })`. Until you refresh the application the data are available around the app. If you want your data to persist after the refresh (and without call the action again) you need to use `AsyncStorage` or `redux-persist`.

Comment: Thank you very much Marco. Just 1 more question if you don't mind: How can we attach those data sent to  the cloud to the user who are authenticated ? Like when the user signs in, he/she can see the data he/she created ?

Comment: @Marwin there are many ways to do that. For example, you can add a property `userId` with the `uid` of the user to the document  `.add({
      name: "Marco",
      born: "1993", userId: ...
    })`.